# Как записывать строки в начала в не в конец файла?

Tags: php

Есть код который добавляет строки в файл, но в конец файла, а как сделать что бы добавляло в начало файла? И также хотел узнать а есть ли способ дописовать именно во 2 строчку файла?

```
<?php
if ($_POST['']);
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$link = htmlspecialchars($_POST['link']);
$space = '  ';
// строка, которую будем записывать со всеми переносами
$text = "$name\n$link\n$space\n";

// открываем файл, если файл не существует, делается попытка создать его
$fp = fopen("abc.txt", "a+");

// записываем
fwrite($fp, $text);

// закрываем
fclose($fp);
echo 'Данные записаны';
?>
```

Comment: Создать новый файл. Скопировать в него первые n строк из старого файла, туда же записать m новых строк, скопировать оставшиеся строки из старого файла. Удалить старый файл, переименовать новый в старый.

Comment: А есть ли в php memory mapped файлы? Тогда можно попытаться свести задачу к простому перемещению массивов байтов (и возможно куда более сложных объектов) с одного адреса памяти на другой.

Comment: Файловая система позволяет дописывать только в конец, это физическое ограничение. Но вы всегда можете перезаписывать файл целиком. С точки зрения файловой системы нет понятия строк, поэтому нет, напрямую записывать в какую-то строку невозможно, возможно оперировать только позицией внутри файла.

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, указание режима "c+" не сильно поможет, так как данные будут не дописаны, а перезаписаны в начале файла. По крайней мере у меня так.

Я бы рекомендовал такое решение:

```
$text = "ваш текст";
$text .= file_get_contents("abc.txt"); //читаем и "дописываем" в начало текста
file_put_contents("abc.txt", "\xEF\xBB\xBF".  $text ); //записываем обратно c BOM согласно комментарию
```

Comment: как сделать что бы котировка не менялась а оставалась Utf-8 ?

Comment: Зависит от того, какие у вас там проблемы. Вот тут достаточно решений: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format. Ну и, раз возникла такая проблема, убедитесь, что сам скрипт и файл у вас в utf-8.

Comment: Вот что я сделал - везде стоит котировка utf-8 но потом когда что то добвоялем файл автоматически становиться urf-8 без bom http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLLqvN

Comment: Ну так вы, видимо, 3 байта бом постоянно перезаписываете. По указанной мной ссылке это тоже есть.

Comment: Можете именно в код это вставить а то не могу разобраться в этом.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Замечу, что там только BOM добавляется. Если файлы просто в utf-8 без BOM, то все и так работает.

Comment: мне нужно что бы оно так и оставлось в utf-8 и не становилось utf-8 без Bom

Comment: Мне кажется, вы начали углубляться не в ту тему. На заданный вами изначально вопрос работающий ответ дан. Ошибку с UTF-8, если она есть, задайте в новом вопросе. У меня, как я уже и писал, utf-8 кодировка в файле сохраняется, когда изначально и файл, и скрипт в utf-8. Возможно, у вас где-то еще проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Указать [mode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php) "c+" (указатель на файл будет установлен на начало файла): `$fp = fopen("abc.txt", "c+");`

А для того что бы установить указатель на заданную позицию нужно использовать [fseek](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fseek.php), только для этого надо считать количество байт (не символов) на которое надо сместить указатель.

Answer (score 0):

Писать в начало можно через режим для `fopen` - `c+`, что отметил @VladVlad.
Но если нужно дописать/переписать определённую строку, то проще так:

```
$str = 'myString';     // Строка
$file = file('1.txt'); // Читаем файл в массив: 1 элемент - одна строка

// Пишем в начало: добавляем строку с \n в начало (0 позиция) массива строк
array_unshift($file, $str . "\n"); 

// Заменить строку: меняем элемент массива с индексом [N-строки - 1] (с нуля же считаем)
// Оригинальную строку очищаем trim'ом, там в конце \n лишний
// В конце добавляем опять \n, чтобы строки не слиплись :)
$file[1] = trim($file[1]) . $str . "\n";

// Сливаем массив в строку и записываем его обратно
file_put_contents('1.txt', implode("", $file));
```