# Запись строки в начало файла php

Tags: php, строки

Нужно записать строку в начало текстового файла. 
Делаю запись следующим образом:

```
$err_out=$path_catalog.$out;
$temp = fopen($err_out, "r+");
$text = "Не удалось скопировать файлы:";
fwrite($temp, $text . "\r\n"); 
fclose($temp);
```

Строка `$text` в файл записывается, но при этом затираются символы последующей (уже существующей на момент записи) строки. 
Какие существуют способы решения данной проблемы?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535836/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/535847#535847 здесь есть ответ. Правда, автор вопроса забыл его принять.

Answer (score 2):

Решения, на выбор:

1. не записывать куда-либо, кроме как в конец файла
2. перезаписывать файл целиком. Сначала новую строку, затем всё, что в файле было ранее

Файловые системы не умеют писать перед файлом, только вместо. Можно сделать запись нового содержимого в конец малой ценой, консистентная вставка (а не замена) куда-либо кроме конца файла - без перезаписи файла невозможна.

Можете использовать какую-нибудь СУБД. Например, встраиваемую `sqlite`. Тогда она возьмёт на себя проблемы записи и ворох других граблей и вы сможете читать в нужном вам порядке просто указав обычный `order by`

Answer (score 1):

Воспользовавшись советом @Gino Pane, решила проблему следующим образом:

```
$text = "Не удалось скопировать файлы: \n";
$text .= file_get_contents($err_out) . PHP_EOL; //читаем и "дописываем" в начало текста
file_put_contents($err_out, $text ."\n");
```

где $err_out - файл, в который необходимо дописать строку $text 
Результат выглядит так:

```
Не удалось скопировать файлы: 
copy "..\SourceDotNet\WebClient\WebClient.Web\RSB_WebClient.aspx" to "..\Distrib\WebClient" 
copy "..\SourceDotNet\WebClient\WebClient.Web\Web.config" to "..\Distrib\WebClient" 
copy "..\SourceDotNet\WebClient\WebClient.Web\Silverlight.js" to "..\Distrib\WebClient" 
copy "..\SourceDotNet\WebClient\WebClient.Web\FileUpload.ashx" to "..\Distrib\WebClient"
```