# Добавление строк в начало, а не в конец файла

Tags: php

Использую следующий код для отзывов на сайте, они записываются в конец файла, новый отзыв в низу файла, а в верху файла старый отзыв. Как записать в верх файла новый отзыв? Код:

```
< ?
if ($_GET['c'] == '')
    {
    print "

<form>
  <input type='hidden'  name='c' value='obr' />
  <input type='text' id='reviews_form_name' name='name' placeholder='Имя' value='' /><br />
  <textarea name='content' id='reviews_form_text' placeholder='Отзыв...'></textarea><br />

  <input type='submit' id='button_form_reviews' value='Оставить свой отзыв' />
</form>
";
    $fp = fopen("comment.txt", "r"); // Открываем файл в режиме чтения
    if ($fp)
        {
        while (!feof($fp))
            {
            $mytext = fgets($fp, 999);
            echo $mytext . "<br />";
            }
        }
      else echo "Ошибка при открытии файла";
    fclose($fp);
    }
elseif ($_GET['c'] == 'obr')
    {

    // заносим в массив значение полей

    $znach = array(
        1 => $_GET['name'],
        3 => $_GET['content']
    );
    if (!$znach[1])
        {
        print "Поле <b>Имя</b>, незаполненно <br /> <meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='4; url=javascript:history.go(-1);' ><a href='javascript:history.go(-1);'><<<Назад</a> <br />";
        }
      else
    if (!$znach[3])
        {
        print "Поле <b>Отзыв</b>, незаполненно <br /> <meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='4; url=javascript:history.go(-1);' ><a href='javascript:history.go(-1);'><<<Назад</a> <br />";
        }
      else
        {
        $fp = fopen("comment.txt", "a+"); // Открываем файл в режиме записи
        $mytext = "\n\n\r\n" . "Дата: " . date('Y:m:d') . "\r\n" . "Имя: " . $znach[1] . "\r\n" . "Отзыв: " . "\r\n" . $znach[3] . "\r\n";
        $test = fwrite($fp, $mytext); // Запись в файл
        if ($test) echo 'Данные в файл успешно занесены.';
          else echo 'Ошибка при записи в файл.';
        fclose($fp); //Закрытие файла
        print "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; url=?c=' >";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Вопросы цикличны как и все в этом мире... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538905/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сделал цикл который считывает файл снизу вверх. Код:

```
$fp = file("comment.txt");
$fp = array_reverse($fp);
foreach($fp as $f){
    echo $f."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Это ответ или продолжение вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

По-простому, без претензии на эффективность, можно так:

```
$file = 'comment.txt';
$mytext = "новый комментарий\r\n";
file_put_contents($file, $mytext . @file_get_contents($file));
```