# Как записать в самое начало строки в текстовом файл в php?

Tags: php, строки

не могу записать данные с начала строки

вот код

```
    **<?php
    $datavnes=$_POST['datavnes'];
    $datapost = $_POST['datapost']; 
    $jur = $_POST['jur']; 
    $summ = $_POST['summ'];
    $numberpp = $_POST['numberpp'];
    $org = $_POST['org'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
    $man = $_POST['man'];
    $file_change="\n $datavnes;$datapost;$jur;$summ;$numberpp;$org;$notes;$man";
    $file=fopen("db/items.txt", "a+");
    fputs($file,$file_change."\r\n");
    fclose($file);
    ?>
<form method="post">
Добавить<br/>
<input placeholder="Дата внес." type="text" name="datavnes" /><br/>
<input placeholder="Дата пост." type="text" name="datapost" /><br/> 
<input placeholder="Юр. лицо" type="text" name="jur" /><br/> 
<input placeholder="Сумма" type="text" name="summ" /><br/> 
<input placeholder="Номер п/п" type="text" name="numberpp" /><br/> 
<input placeholder="Организация" type="text" name="org" /><br/>
<input placeholder="Примечание" type="text" name="notes" /> <br/>
<input placeholder="Менеджер" type="text" name="man" /><br/> 
<input type="submit" name="btn" />
</form>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>добавить товар</title>
 </head>
 <body>**
```

Comment: вы хотите добавлять данные в начало файла, а не в конец? Только считывать файл полностью и перезаписывать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запись строки в начало файла php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538905/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведу пример, который не относится к вашим данным:

```php
$file_data = "Stuff you want to add\n";
$file_data .= file_get_contents('database.txt');
file_put_contents('database.txt', $file_data);
?>
```

То есть, получаете сначала контент из файла и добавляете его (так как он строка) к своему тексту. Потом просто перезаписываете файл.

Либо используйте атрибуты метода `fopen`:

> 'r'   Открывает файл только для чтения; помещает указатель в начало
>   файла.
>
> 'r+'  Открывает файл для чтения и записи; помещает указатель в начало
>   файла.
>
> 'w'   Открывает файл только для записи; помещает указатель в начало
>   файла и обрезает файл до нулевой длины. Если файл не существует -
>   пробует его создать.
>
> 'w+'  Открывает файл для чтения и записи; помещает указатель в начало
>   файла и обрезает файл до нулевой длины. Если файл не существует -
>   пытается его создать.
>
> 'a'   Открывает файл только для записи; помещает указатель в конец
>   файла. Если файл не существует - пытается его создать. В данном режиме
>   функция fseek() не применима, записи всегда добавляются в конец.
>
> 'a+'  Открывает файл для чтения и записи; помещает указатель в конец
>   файла. Если файл не существует - пытается его создать. В данном режиме
>   функция fseek() влияет только на позицию чтения, записи всегда
>   добавляются в конец.
>
> 'x'   Создаёт и открывает только для записи; помещает указатель в начало
>   файла. Если файл уже существует, вызов fopen() закончится неудачей,
>   вернёт FALSE и выдаст ошибку уровня E_WARNING. Если файл не
>   существует, попытается его создать. Это эквивалентно указанию флагов
>   O_EXCL|O_CREAT для внутреннего системного вызова open(2).
>
> 'x+'  Создаёт и открывает для чтения и записи; в остальном имеет то же
>   поведение, что и'x'.
>
> 'c'   Открывает файл только для записи. Если файл не существует, то он
>   создается. Если же файл существует, то он не обрезается (в отличие от
>   'w'), и вызов к этой функции не вызывает ошибку (также как и в случае
>   с 'x'). Указатель на файл будет установлен на начало файла. Это может
>   быть полезно при желании заблокировать файл (см. flock()) перед
>   изменением, так как использование 'w' может обрезать файл еще до того
>   как была получена блокировка (если вы желаете обрезать файл, можно
>   использовать функцию ftruncate() после запроса на блокировку).
>
> 'c+'  Открывает файл для чтения и записи; в остальном имеет то же
>   поведение, что и 'c'.
>
> 'e'   Установить флаг close-on-exec (закрыть при запуске) на открытый
>   файловый дескриптор. Доступно только в PHP скомпилированном на
>   системах поддерживающих POSIX.1-2008

Эту информацию можно было прочитать в [документации метода fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php)

Comment: привет то что нужно все работает

Comment: Молодец, скопировал другой ответ и добавил бессмысленную цитату из мануала для объема

Comment: @Ипатьев ровно как и задают бессмысленные вопросы. Какой вопрос - такой ответ. Дубликат же вот дубль ответа. А с другой стороны, я поискал за него и выдал информацию, которая ему поможет решит его проблему. Зачем придумывать велосипед? :D

Comment: и все - ради циферок кармочки